# Ошибка версии ChromeDriver

Tags: chromedriver

Если после установки хромдрайвера ловите:

```
version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84","stacktrace":"#0 '
     '0x5596f6ff3ea
```

Comment: «[самоответы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6300/178576)» здесь, конечно, приветствуются, но, пожалуйста, оформите его в виде отдельных вопроса и ответа.

Answer (score 0):

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Найти версию драйвера равную вашей версии браузера

```
$ cd /opt && sudo mkdir webdriver && cd webdriver
$ sudo wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ВЕРСИЯ/chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

где ВЕРСИЯ - версия нужного вебдрайвера, например, 87.0.4280.88 (https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

```
$ sudo unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && sudo chmod 755 chromedriver && sudo rm chromedriver_linux64.zip

$ sudo ln -s /opt/webdriver/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

обновите его и перенесите сюда:

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/webdriver/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Если есть проблемы ChromeDriver - напишите ниже. Пригодится.